# exit ssh when prompt for new password

Tags: ssh, password, exit

I am looking for a way to exit ssh when password expires.
I have a script that is checking few things on all VMs in infrastructure.
Unfortunately there are few VMs with password auth method.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Password expiry messages are shown after ssh has authenticated, this is not something you can do with ssh alone.

You'll need to use [expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/) (tcl), [Expect.pm](https://metacpan.org/dist/Expect) (perl), [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect) (python) or any one of dozens of similar expect-like libraries for various languages.

These all provide the ability to script interactions with various programs (including remote login sessions via ssh or telnet or whatever), looking for particular patterns and sending appropriate responses.

BTW, perl has a [Net::SSH](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-SSH) for automating ssh sessions and providing expect-like features.  A specialised implementation of expect for ssh.  Some other languages have similar specialised libraries.